# Defining a protocol for TCP IP Data transfer from Raspberry (Using 4G modedm [Quectel ec25]) to Linux Socket Server

Tags: python, tcp, modem, 4g, quectel

I have a RPi 4 + Sixfab Base HAT + Quectel EC25 4G LTE modem + Picam and I am trying to develop a program to take pictures from picam and send them over 4G using TCP/IP protocol and then receive and display the picture on Linux Socket Server.

I don't have alot of experience with this, and have seen some Socket programming information but it does not completely fit for me because I am using Quectel 4G modem instead of wifi or ethernet - which means I can't use socket. functions, but only AT commands.

So far, I can send a small 20x20 png encoded with base64 from Rpi with 4G and receive it in socket server but cannot reconstruct the small image.

But if the data gets larger I need to define a protocol (File size,  start - end - etc. ) . I have seen some custom protocols but they are only for socket servers and not incorporate the use of 4G modems. I would appreciate if anyone can guide me in the right direction. .

```
if ser.isOpen(): # if modem is open
try:
        ser.flushInput() 
        ser.flushOutput()

        BG96 = bg96_init()  # initialize function for the Modem

        i = 0
    encoded = ""
        #start = time.time()
        while BG96:# 
                if i==0:# does something the first time but not relevant here << 
            print(i)
        encoded = base64.b64encode(open('testingimg.png', 'rb').read())
                print("Data size to send to 4G module:" , sys.getsizeof(encoded))
        print("The Image String: " , encoded)
        bg96_msg(encoded) # This is a function that sends the data via TCP with AT commands 

        encoded=""
        
        ser.flushInput() 
        ser.flushOutput()
        i = i+
        time.sleep(0.33)
```

Comment: and the Function bg_msg is :

def bg96_msg(msgs):
 sendATcommand("AT+QISEND=0",">")
 sendATcommand(msgs + "\x1A","SEND OK")
 msgs=""

Comment: Is low level AT commands a requirement? I have setup this Hat using modemmanager and qmi and use it as a normal connection.

Answer (score 0):

how do you connect EC25 to rpi? if you use USB you don't have to use AT command set and you pi connects to the internet directly over 4g modem.

Comment: Yes via USB. That's also a choice, but in my case i cannot make it default to 4G .  the QMI interface i can't complete... I think it's because of the SIM card not having static IP.

Comment: Maybe it requires a static IP SIM card in order to complete the QMI  Autoconnect for 4G on boot... and also I need the ethernet open to SSH the headless Rpi... Yes maybe the whole issue is actually to have 4G modem active and default on boot.. then I can use normal socket programming??

Comment: Normally if you send anything from rpi to a server you don't need a static IP. (I don't know about your service provider) If you use that modem like standard dial up modem then you can use normal socket programming like on any other network.

Comment: Yes, thank you. The static IP i think is needed to be able to make the Rpi boot and default + initilize the 4G modem for internet. [Also static IP is good in order to SSH the Rpi] ----- If I go with the solution of non-default Modem  then I need to implement a Protocol for my TCP IP Data transfer using AT commands. . This brings us back to my original question. Any possible directions I could start looking at? Because the Socket. functions use native internet connection, so I can't use them with the modem..

Comment: Here is Quectel's EC25 At manual [link](https://www.quectel.com/UploadImage/Downlad/Quectel_EC25&EC21_AT_Commands_Manual_V1.3.pdf) at page 213/215 you would see tcp/ip commands. Also [there](https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~mahlert/TCPIP_Implementation/TCPIP_Implementation.pdf) is a good paper about TCP/IP implementation. And there is one more way of connection that i can't find the script but you can search about it. Raspberry ppp connection. It provides rpi a network connection using serial port and at.

Comment: https://sixfab.com/ppp-installer-for-sixfab-shield-hat/    This? I tried last week and couldnt make it work, Ill give it another try today with the PPP